# Python How to compare data in a certain column when their values in a different column match?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, iteration

I'm currently taking data from SQL in hopes of calculating the biggest difference between data points with the same identifiers.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('SQLdata.csv')
```

Sample data for this df looks like

```
Year,Case
2015,1A
2016,1A
2017,1A
2015,2F
2018,2F
```

I'm hoping to write a script that will add a new column for the difference between the min(Year) and max(Year) for each case. Something like this:

```
Year,Case,YearDifference
2015,1A,2
2016,1A,2
2017,1A,2
2015,2F,3
2018,2F,3
```

I've tried to write a for loop, but got stuck when trying to do it specific for each case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `groupby` and `transform` to subtract the max date from the min date for each group

```
grp = df.groupby('Case')['Year']
df['Diff'] = grp.transform(max).sub(grp.transform(min))
```

You can also try to use `groupby.agg` to get the min and max year for each group and map the difference back to the `Case`

```
df['Diff'] = df['Case'].map(df.groupby('Case')['Year'].agg([min, max])
                            .diff(axis=1)['max'])
```

Out

```
   Year Case  Diff
0  2015   1A     2
1  2016   1A     2
2  2017   1A     2
3  2015   2F     3
4  2018   2F     3
```

Comment: Thank you so much--was able to do it with a groupby transform sequence